# Creating a PyMemoryView with a specific format

Tags: python-c-api

I am exposing a PyMemoryView in C on a set of data, like so:

```
PyMemoryView_FromMemory((char *)ibuf->rect, pixels * sizeof(uint), PyBUF_WRITE);
```

That data is floating-point data, however, so attempting to do this:

```
mv = get_my_memory_view()
mv[0] = 3.141
```

yields the following error:

> TypeError: memoryview: invalid type for format 'B'

This is, of course, because the memoryview assumes the underlying data to be byte data, not float. How would I ensure that the memoryview returned from my module has a float specifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use [the `cast` method of the memoryview](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview.cast) to get a new memoryview with the correct format. There isn't a direct C-API method to do it, so just call it like any other Python method:

```
mview_double = PyObject_CallMethod(mview_bytes, "cast", "s", "d");
```

this assumes `double` data - if it's `float` data then you should change the `"d"`.

---

In the original call to `PyMemoryView_FromMemory` I think `pixels * sizeof(uint)` is wrong since you've told us the data-type is a floating-point type. Maybe `pixels*sizeof(ibuf->rect[0])`?

Comment: Thanks, works great. The original call I copy-pasted from from another part of the code, just an oversight.